# When should I break into GUI/game development?

Tags: user-interface, sdk

I am a hobbyist console C++ developer. I have worked with pointers, arrays, std::vectors, std::strings, classes, and several data structures, including stacks and binary trees. I have some experience in linear algebra and geometry, and know the basics of physics. I do NOT have experience with win32, QT, openGL, DX9, OGRE, etc. I am still learning about the more valuable parts of OOP, like polymorphism.

I started C++ as a first language, and do not have experience with other languages. I could probably work with C, but I'd need to get used to manipulating char*'s and regular arrays (and not initing variables).

My question is, with my experience, when should I break into the development of GUI applications/game applications? Do I need to ground myself more firmly in certain areas of math, become comfortable with win32, get used to  SDK?

If this question is too subjective for you to comfortably give advice, then when did you break into GUI/game development, and what steps did you take to make yourself comfortable with it?

Editing this so it will get bumped. Does anyone else have any opinions?

Comment: Please read the entire post before voting to close/calling it subjective. I gave you an alternative answer, please do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caveat: I am a very "learn-by-doing" type of person, so take this with a grain of salt.

Sounds like you know enough programming basics to jump into something more realistic, and have enough background to justify that realistic project being a game.

I'd recommend downloading [Visual C# Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vcsharp/) and [Microsoft's XNA Game Studio 3.0](http://creators.xna.com/).

XNA is a game framework that has a lot of stuff done for you (sound, sprites, 3D support, etc.) built on a professional-quality C# platform and it would be a good starting point. Create a new XNA project and play around. Get some stuff to appear on the screen, then learn to manipulate it with user input. If you are interested in 3D, make a 3D shape such as a triangle. Then, make it spin. Then, make it spin based on user input. Then, add other objects and collisions.

Surely, there will be things in the framework that you don't understand. Tackle them as they come - use Google and ask questions here until you do understand them. Take it one step at a time and you should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally recommend you to start out with Win32; try creating a basic window & move on from that point. Try making a simple 2D game engine in which you are able to make a game like chess or so. This could also serve as project for which you could write an AI; which is another part of Game Development!

After you finish that, the next step should be 3D. You could use the engine you wrote before and modify it from 2D to 3D. Pick a 3D API; OpenGL or DirectX. Once you have a basic engine, start writing a game. Need extra functionality? Then add it to the engine!

Math-wise you should know what matrices are. Trigonometry can come in handy as well.

I wouldn't waste my time with Xna, it's just a hype. :P

Answer (score 1):

It seems you already have gained the basic knowledge of a programming language to start game programming. I'm with you in building on what you have already gained, such as learning OOP, and practicing more with pointers. I recommend you move on and don't turn to learning another tool "programming language" to achieve your goals.

So if you are interested in game programming, I recommend you pick a C++ framework and work on it, you'll definitely learn more advanced programming by just using it.

I recommend [Gosu](http://www.libgosu.org/). It's not full of advanced features, which can be an advantage, but it has a very clean design and uses C++ in an elegant and modern way. Which makes it very friendly especially for beginners.

Also [HGE](http://hge.relishgames.com/) is another good 2D engine.

To sum up, dive into programming more by actually "doing it" with what you have now. That's how you'll progress, and you'll be amazed with the results. And when "doing it" don't get disturbed with other languages and tools you already know something similar to it, and at the same time when learning a tool that helps you to build on your current knowledge, in your case I mean the C++ engine, don't choose very complicated ones (IMO, like OpenGL, DirectX, Win32...etc) because you'll end up spending time on learning the tool not using it and there is a great chance you'll get frustrated. You can always learn the low level things later, and it will make a lot more sense then.

Answer (score 1):

as this question is kind of subjective, because every programmer has a favourite library to start with, I will recommend [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) as it is simple, well structured, and very complete, there are a lot of tutorials out there to guide you step-by-step from making a simple window to complex 3D manipulation. Everything can be implemented with ease.

As a side note, if you want to start programming games, I would recommend, also, that you read some tuts or books about a Game basics (initialization, game loop, update cycles), so that you know how to put your knowledge to the good work.